# Unidirectional one-to-one relationship with shared primary key and @OneToOne on child side

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an Appliance entity as follows:

```
public class Appliance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other appliance fields
 }
```

Then I have another class that is used to map a third party appliance to an appliance:

```
public class ThirdPartyApplianceMapping {

    @Id
    private Long applianceId;

    private Long thirdPartyApplianceId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="applianceId", nullable=false)
    private Appliance appliance;

 }
```

I want the database to be structured as:

```
Appliance(
     id PK,
     -- other columns but no col reference to ThirdPartyApplianceMapping
)

ThirdPartyApplianceMapping(
     applianceId PK FK references Appliance.id,
     thirdPartyApplianceId
)
```

How can I define / annotate my entities such that the `ThirdPartyApplianceMapping.applianceId` is a PK and FK back to `Appliance.id`? `Appliance` must not be aware of `ThirdPartyApplianceMapping`. I'm using Hibernate's implementation of JPA 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with the help of [MapsId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html):

> Designates a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship attribute that
>   provides the mapping for an EmbeddedId primary key, an attribute
>   within an EmbeddedId primary key, or a simple primary key of the
>   parent entity.

In this case `appliance` should be annotated with `MapsId`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="applianceId")
@MapsId
private Appliance appliance;
```

Also `nullable=false` was dropped, because by definition primary key is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

> The @Id annotation or id XML attribute can be added to a OneToOne or
>   ManyToOne mapping. The Id used for the object will be derived from the
>   target object's Id. If the Id is a single value, then the source
>   object's Id is the same as the target object's Id.

Source: [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)

So for your case this should do it:

```
public class ThirdPartyApplianceMapping {

    private Long thirdPartyApplianceId;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="applianceId", nullable=false)
    private Appliance appliance;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that results in the following error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable`.

Comment: There is most likely a second @Id annotation. Do you want a composed primary key?

Comment: No. `Appliance` has only a single `@Id` on its instance field `id`. I want `ThirdPartyApplianceMapping` to have that as its foreign key back to `Appliance` and as its primary key.

Comment: One. The `@Id` annotation as you noted in your answer.